# const pod and std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

To get this code to compile:

```
std::vector<Foo> factory() 
{
    std::vector<Foo> data;
    return data;
}
```

I have to define my POD like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    const int i;
    const int j;

    Foo(const int _i, const int _j): i(_i), j(_j) {}

    Foo(Foo& foo): i(foo.i), j(foo.j){}

    Foo operator=(Foo& foo)
    {
        Foo f(foo.i, foo.j);
        return f;
    }
};
```

Is this the correct approach for defining a pod where I'm not interested in changing the pod members after creation? Why am I forced to define a copy constructor and overload the assignment operator? Is this compatible for different platform implementations of `std::vector`? Is it wrong in your opinion to have const PODS like this? Should I just leave them as non-const?

Comment: Your `operator=` is nonsensical; instead of assigning the members of the left operand (which cannot be done) you create a new object and return it. How is that assignment?

Comment: @CodingMash Do that and you'll be returning a reference to a temporary

Comment: My bad, thats worse.
I only saw the prototype.
It should be `return *this` and a lot more before. :)

Comment: Your type isn't a POD, since it has (and needs) a user-defined constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behavior to create an `std::vector` over a type that you can't assign.  You can't assign POD's with `const` members.

Comment: And beside that your type isn't a POD at all, POD types can't have user defined constructor or `operator==`

Answer (score 0):

You ask several questions:

> > Is this the correct approach for defining a pod where I'm not interested in changing the pod members after creation?

Your question is ill-formed because you **are** interested in changing the pod members after creation. By using `std::vector`, you are asking `vector::resize()`, for example, permission to modify all of the members of your objects via the assignment operator.

Also, as others have pointed out, your `operator=` doesn't make much sense. It surely doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically, after the expression `a=b`, the members of `a` are unchanged.

> > Why am I forced to define a copy constructor and overload the assignment operator?

Because you are using `std::vector`. Consider C++2003, §23.1/3, "The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of `CopyConstructible`
types, and the additional requirements of `Assignable` types."

Practically speaking, it is because `vector` needs to be able to move your objects around while it does its memory-management.

> > Is this compatible for different platform implementations of `std::vector`?

Yes. For any implementation of `std::vector`, your type must be CopyConstructible and Assignable.

> > Is it wrong in your opinion to have const PODS like this?

Yes, it contradicts your intended usage. You intend to put them into a vector, where they will be modified.

> > Should I just leave them as non-const?

Yes. If you leave them as non-const, then you don't need a user-defined copy constructor nor a user-defined assignment operator.